# jQuery - loop through multidimensional array and append data from next or prev array

Tags: jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am creating a slideshow and i have an multidimensional array with data informations. Array looks like this, ofcourse it will be longer, maximum 20 arrays in imageList.

```
var imagesList = [
   [1, 112, "<img src=\"http://example.com/test/images/1/112.jpg\" />", "http://example.com/test/photos/image-112", "Title 1"],
   [2, 115, "<img src=\"http://example.com/test/images/1/115.jpg\"/>", "http://example.com/test/photos/image-115", "Title 2"],
   [3, 116, "<img src=\"http://example.com/test/images/2/116.jpg\"/>", "http://example.com/test/photos/image-116", "Title 3"]
];
```

When slideshow openes i set the first array as current image:

```
var curentImage = imagesList[0];
```

I am appending the image informations like this:

```
imageArea.append(curentImage[2]);
title.text(curentImage[4]);
```

There are navigation arrows, left and right.

```
rightNav.click( function(){
   //What goes here?
});
```

How can i loop through imagesList array and append informations for next image? or previous image when

```
leftNav.click( function(){
   //What goes here?
});
```

Comment: as i see it, you'd have better to use an array of object

Answer (score 0):

You just need to keep track of a counter.  A global variable to your script that you increment or decrement based on left / right click.

```
var index = 0;

//slideshow open
var currentImage = currentList[index];

//right
counter ? counter > currentList.length - 1 : 0 : counter+=1;
//display image

//left
counter ? counter < 0 ? currentList.length - 1 : 0;
//display image
```

I would have a generic function that can get the right image from the list using counter, and does all the display logic, so it can be called from anywhere (open, left, right)